# time delay in counter

Tags: counter, delay, propagation

For the ring oscillator shown in teh figure 1

[image],

A ring oscillator consisting of 5 inverters is running at a frequency of 1 MHz. the propagation delay per each gate is?

One possible solution for this question is:

t(out)=t (1 to 0)+ t (0 to 1)
      =5T+5T
      = 10T

1/f(out)=10T

T=0.1 micro second

I want to know why am i not able to solve this question as given :

we know that

f(out)= f (clk)/number of states

t(out)=t(clk)*number of states

```
  =2*N*T(delay of flip flop)*number of states

  =2*5*T*5
```

1/f(out) =50*T

10^-6 =50*T

T=0.02 microsecond

Comment: Add a proper circuit diagrams as images and text as plain text to your question. The images are unclear, the text hard to read and the question cannot be indexed by search engines rendering most of the efforts useless for future visitors.

Comment: Where is figure 2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you've missed something. Your equations make no sense.

1) Tclk = N Td  - Wrong. N Td is the delay through the inverter chain. As you posted, Tclk = 2 x N x Td. A rising edge at the input of the left-hand inverter will take 5 delays to reappear as a falling edge, then another 5 to show up as a rising edge.

2) Tclk = 5 Td should then be 10 Td.

After that, it just gets incomprehensible. What is Tout? By your notes, Tout = N Tclk, and substituting gives Tout = N squared Tclk. With that as a starting point, none of the rest of the page makes any sense at all.

And finally, the last two lines show Td = 1 / 25 x 10^6, Td = .0416 x 10^-6.

You really ought to know that 1 / 25 does not equal .0416.

Comment: sir can u please tell me why am i still not able to get the right answer

Comment: 1/f=T*2*number of stages (assuming T0->1 and T1->0 are equal). Therefore for your circuit it's 1/10^6=T*2*5 -> T=10^-5 -> 0.1 usec

Comment: Sorry. It's T = 10^-6/10 = 10^-7 = 0.1 usec

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the ring oscillator is 1 MHz, that means that like edges appearing at its  output must be 1 microsecond apart.

So, assuming that the output edge of the rightmost inverter in the chain has just gone positive, it'll appear as the input to the first inverter almost instantaneously and, some time later, the output of the first inverter will go low. That low will be presented to the input of the second inverter and, some time later, the second inverter will output a high which will be presented to the input of the third inverter, and so on.

Bottom line is that since there are 5 delay stages in the oscillator and the last stage must wait for its output edge to ripple through time before it can change state, the delay through each stage must be 200 nanoseconds.